# How to filter in array of objects by the text provided by user in search box?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to filter the objects by searched text. I used `filter` method, but it outputs `undefined`. For example, I want to filter the quotes by "Albert Einstein" when user enters it in the search box.

Here is quotes data: https://type.fit/api/quotes

[image]

[image]

```
const Search = ({
  selectedData,
  setSelectedData,
  randomNumber,
  setRandomNumber,
}) => {
  const onChange = (element) => {
    console.log(element.target.value)
    return element.target.value
  }
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const newData = selectedData.filter((item) => item.author === onChange)
    console.log(newData)
  }

  return (
    <div className="search">
      <form role="search" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input
          id="search"
          className="search-bar"
          type="search"
          placeholder="Albert Einstein"
          onChange={onChange}
          autoFocus
          required
        />
        <button className="fas fa-search" type="submit"></button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Search
```

Comment: After entering the name of the famous person in my search line and doing onSubmit, I am trying to write a code that displays the articles belonging to her.

Comment: I edited the share, you can see the screen output and the component I wrote.
There are values ​​in selectedData that I got from api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do:

```
selectedData.filter(
  (item) => item.author.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) > -1
)
```

And you should store `searchText` with `onChange` handler of input field.

An example:

```js
function App() {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState('')
  const [quotes, setQuotes] = React.useState([
  {
    "text": "Genius is one percent inspiration and ninety-nine percent perspiration.",
    "author": "Thomas Edison"
  },
  {
    "text": "You can observe a lot just by watching.",
    "author": "Yogi Berra"
  }
  ])

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {quotes
          .filter((q) => {
             return q.author.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) > -1
          })
          .map((q) => (
            <div>{q.author} | {q.text}</div>
          ))}
      </div>
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('mydiv'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
</body>
```